# Xdebug + IntelliJ: Debugger is always one line behind real set breakpoint

Tags: php, intellij-idea, vagrant, phpstorm, xdebug

In my Symfony application I am using IntelliJ Ultimate + Xdebug + Vagrant VM with an remote debug setting in IntelliJ. In the Vagrant box there is PHP 7.2 and Xdebug 2.6 installed

When I start a debug session via browser, everything works fine. I can step through all my code perfectly.

But when I start a remote debug session inside VM via

```
 XDEBUG_CONFIG="remote_host=10.10.0.1" PHP_IDE_CONFIG="serverName=abc" bin/console <command>
```

The Xdebug works also but it misses the lines in my local source code. In IntelliJ I am always one line ahead as the debugger seems to be. I can see it when for example a new variable is created in my local source code. Just one step later the debugger info shows me, that it was created. Another example: if I step over a code line I am suddenly on an empty line.

If I set the breakpoint as follows

```
  $a = "abc";
o echo $a;

  echo "test";
```

The debugger stops, but `$a` isn't initialized yet (as seen in the variables section). If I now step over

```
  $a = "abc";
  echo $a;
o
  echo "test";
```

`$a` is initialized now, but not outputted by the `echo` command and the debugger is on an empty line.

Next step over leads to

```
  $a = "abc";
  echo $a;

  echo "test";
o
```

and so on ...

The only tip I can find is: Check the path mapping. I am sure, the path mapping is really okay because it actually finds all the files I want to debug but it stops on the wrong line.

I also compared the files in my vagrant source code and my local source code. They are exactly the same. I think they cannot be out of sync cause the source code is shared with the VM via shared folder.

I also looked into Xdebug log file which tells me line numbers. These line numbers are exactly the same as in my local code, so nothing unusual here.

Strange is: The `bin/console` php file works correct, but classes instantiated from here does not.

Does somebody has a clue, what I can check else? Is there a known bug or anything else? Its no option to debug all my command line executed code via `die()` and `print()` commands ...

Comment: Wow that's a complicated one, if even `<- breakpoint_set` statements show you correct lines... I suggest you try using a different [Xdebug client](https://xdebug.org/docs/remote), and if the issue persists there - try to re-create your virtual environment. If debugging works OK in the other client, please submit a ticket to us: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us

Comment: I am still on it and found out, that maybe an require_once() command with an generic created autoloader class is guilty ... sometimes it works when i add a empty line before or after that require_once(".../.../autoload.php") statement. I guess that this included class is changing before it gets included ...

Comment: Ok i don't know how to reproduce this. I think i'll give up after 2 days searching this buggy behaviour ...